# VS Community 2015. Debugger cannot break into Windows 7 example driver. Serial connection

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2015, windbg, drivers, kmdf

I am working on this example on writing a simple Windows driver and debugging it from VS:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx

My Setup

- Host: Windows 7 Physical system
- Target: Windows 7 Physical system
- Connection type: Serial cable (USB to serial in host, serial in
  target)

Provisioning the target system is successful. Serial connection parameters are correct (tested the serial connection with different software). Driver is built and installed successfully in the target but "Break all" command does nothing. I am able to attach to a different process in the target.

I have seen similar questions and the usual response is to check for a mismatch between the connection parameters in the host and the target. I have checked this and the parameters are correct.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the target prepared for kernel debugging ?
"bcdedit -debug on  "   and  "bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport:2  BAUDRATE:115200"

Comment: What are your connection parameters? Can't you use Ethernet debugging?

Comment: I also recommend debugging via ethernet. I've only got serial working via virtual machines and named pipe.